# nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying insert some record into one table called LOG but unable to start the application using hibernate and spring, using a builder pattern to generate the object LogBuilder class also included inside the normal entity class. Please suggest to reduce this problem.

```
package com.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG", catalog = "ADM")
public class HistoryLogEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int objid;
    private String sessionId;
    private Date loggedinDate;

    private String browser;
    private String browserVersion;
    private String userId;

    private String action;
    private Date actionDate;
    private String context;

    private String subContext;
    private String operation;
    private int reference;

    private int subReference;
    private int refObjid;
    private int subRefObjid;

    private int programmId;
    private String masterTableRefrence;
    private String oldValue;

    private String newValue;
    private String reason;
    private String description;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OBJID")
        public int getObjid() {
        return objid;
    }

    @Column(name = "SESSION_ID")
    public String getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }

    @Column(name = "LOGGEDIN_DATE")
    public Date getLoggedinDate() {
        return loggedinDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "BROWSER")
    public String getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }

    @Column(name = "BROWSER_VERSION")
    public String getBrowserVersion() {
        return browserVersion;
    }

    @Column(name = "USERID")
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "ACTION")
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    @Column(name = "ACTION_DATE")
    public Date getActionDate() {
        return actionDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "CONTEXT")
    public String getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Column(name = "SUB_CONTEXT")
    public String getSubContext() {
        return subContext;
    }

    @Column(name = "OPERATION")
    public String getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    @Column(name = "REFERENCE")
    public int getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    @Column(name = "SUB_REFERENCE")
    public int getSubReference() {
        return subReference;
    }

    @Column(name = "REF_OBJID")
    public int getRefObjid() {
        return refObjid;
    }

    @Column(name = "SUB_REF_OBJID")
    public int getSubRefObjid() {
        return subRefObjid;
    }

    @Column(name = "PROGRAMM_ID")
    public int getProgrammId() {
        return programmId;
    }

    @Column(name = "MASTER_TABLE_REFRENCE")
    public String getMasterTableRefrence() {
        return masterTableRefrence;
    }

    @Column(name = "OLD_VALUE")
    public String getOldValue() {
        return oldValue;
    }

    @Column(name = "NEW_VALUE")
    public String getNewValue() {
        return newValue;
    }

    @Column(name = "REASON")
    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }


    private HistoryLogEntity(LogBuilder builder) {
        this.sessionId = builder.sessionId;
        this.loggedinDate = builder.loggedinDate;
        this.browser = builder.browser;
        this.browserVersion = builder.browserVersion;
        this.userId = builder.userId;
        this.action = builder.action;
        this.actionDate = new Date();
        this.context = builder.context;
        this.subContext = builder.subContext;
        this.operation = builder.operation;
        this.reference = builder.reference;
        this.subReference = builder.subReference;
        this.refObjid = builder.refObjid;
        this.subRefObjid = builder.subRefObjid;
        this.programmId = builder.programmId;
        this.masterTableRefrence = builder.masterTableRefrence;
        this.oldValue = builder.oldValue;
        this.newValue = builder.newValue;
        this.reason = builder.reason;
        this.description = builder.description;
    }

    // LogBuilder class
    public static class LogBuilder {

        private String sessionId;
        private Date loggedinDate;
        private String browser;

        private String browserVersion;
        private String userId;
        private String action;

        private String context;
        private String subContext;
        private String operation;

        private int reference;
        private int subReference;
        private int refObjid;

        private int subRefObjid;
        public int programmId;
        public String masterTableRefrence;

        private String oldValue;
        private String newValue;
        private String reason;

        private String description;

        public LogBuilder(String sessionId, String userId, String action, String context, String operation) {
            this.sessionId = sessionId;
            this.userId = userId;
            this.context = context;
            this.action = action;
            this.operation = operation;
        }

        public LogBuilder loggedInTime(Date loggedInTime) {
            this.loggedinDate = loggedInTime;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder browser(String browser) {
            this.browser = browser;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder browserVersion(String browserVersion) {
            this.browserVersion = browserVersion;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder subContext(String subContext) {
            this.subContext = subContext;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder operation(String operation) {
            this.operation = operation;
            return this;
        }
        public LogBuilder refObjid(int refObjid) {
            this.refObjid = refObjid;
            return this;
        }
        public LogBuilder programmId(int programmId) {
            this.programmId = programmId;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder masterTableRefrence(String masterTableRefrence) {
            this.masterTableRefrence = masterTableRefrence;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder oldValue(String oldValue) {
            this.oldValue = oldValue;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder newValue(String newValue) {
            this.newValue = newValue;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder subRefObjid(int subRefObjid) {
            this.subRefObjid = subRefObjid;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder subReference(int subReference) {
            this.subReference = subReference;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder reason(String reason) {
            this.reason = reason;
            return this;
        }

        public LogBuilder description(String description) {
            this.description = description;
            return this;
        }

        public HistoryLogEntity build() {
            HistoryLogEntity historyLogEntity = new HistoryLogEntity(this);
            // validateHistoryLogEntityObject(historyLogEntity);
            return historyLogEntity;
        }

        private void validateHistoryLogEntityObject(HistoryLogEntity historyLogEntity) {
            // Do some basic validations to check
        }
    }
}
```

Error Log details which I'm getting from server logs.

```
ERROR DispatcherServlet:502 - Context initialization failed
 Error creating bean with name 'XXXDaoImpl' defined in file [C:\Ajay\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\XXXRestAPI\WEB-INF\classes\com\XXX\dao\impl\XXXDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister; nested exception is
```

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I found the answer,if we have getter methods then we must have setter methods also for every property, Hibernate assume that values will be read from database so so for setting these values it required setter method.

Answer (score -1):

You need no-argument constructor for your HistoryLogEntity